# Altium : Place components in a square with one command

Tags: altium

I remember I have seen someone in the past who could select component in the schematic in cross select mode and then later in the pcb layout to draw a square/rectangle surface, and then all the selected components in the schematic would place automatically in the drawn area in the pcb layout.

Does anyone know what is the procedure to perform this way ? I am a bit tired of dragging component one by one from romm to area where they should be located on the pab board.

Comment: Sounds like a user script to me. I've never found one that works very well, but that should give you a place to start. There's no way to logically place all components as they should be in the finished board automatically. You need to do that yourself (*gasp* You'll have to use your brain!!!).

Comment: no but i kjnow there is a function that allow to do this in native without script,n but i don't remember which one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

[Arrange Components Within Rectangle](http://techdoc.altium.com/display/ADRR/PCB_Cmd-ArrangeComponents_PLPCB~ArrangeComponentsWithinRectangle((Arrange+Components+Within+Rectangle))_AD)

I highly recommend reading some of Altium's techdocs. They clearly explain all of the features included in the Altium package. They're very useful, and will pop up as one of the top hits on Google if you search for your question or for a specific tool. They should be your go-to, not the EE Stack Exchange. Do some research yourself first before asking your questions here. Right now you're just cluttering up the board.

Comment: I don't know what documentation you got but mine doesn't have this inside. I have only module 1, module 2 etc.. 
Where did you get your documentation ? Do you have link to download it?

Comment: I'm referring to the Altium TechDocs. It sounds like you have a primer. The TechDocs are available online: https://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Altium+Designer . However, it is not designed for you to simply read through it. Your best bet would be to google for an answer to your question first, and on the top of the list returned by google you'll probably see a link to the Altium TechDocs. For example, to get the above link I googled "Altium arrange components within rectangle" and it was at the top of the list. Follow this format and you'll find answers a lot faster than you will here.